# Error message for keyboard-chord code: termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a python beginner, and I was recently trying to code a program that required the readchar module. However, I kept getting the error message:

```
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

I've tried adjusting my code, but I keep getting the same error message. Here is my code:

```
import readchar

while True:
    print(readchar.readkey())
```

(This is the full error message.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/larajean/PycharmProjects/thegreatesthits/chordKeyboard.py", line 7, in <module>
chord = readchar.readkey()
   File "/Users/larajean/PycharmProjects/thegreatesthits/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readchar/readchar.py", line 20, in readkey
c1 = getchar()
   File "/Users/larajean/PycharmProjects/thegreatesthits/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readchar/readchar_linux.py", line 12, in readchar
old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

I am using a PyCharm IDE and a version of Python 2.7. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What platform are you on? What terminal are you running the program in?

Comment: Also, all the stuff about playing music, etc. is almost certainly not related to the problem—but it would be very helpful to be certain. If you strip it all out and write a [mcve] that just loops over `print(readchar.readkey())` or something, do you still have the same problem? If so, post _that_ code, and get rid of all the irrelevant code and tags.

Comment: Also, is "the readchar library" [this one](https://pypi.org/project/readchar/)? If so, it looks like it was abandoned without reaching 1.0 status over 4 years ago, and from a quick glance at the GitHub issues, it has a lot of problems. So, it may just be that your environment isn't supported by this library, and you need to pick a different one.

Comment: @abarnert hi- thanks for the reply. I tried it again like you said and am getting the exact same error message.

Comment: OK, that helps. But you still have to answer all of the other questions if you want anyone to be able to debug your problem.

Comment: @abarnert yes, that was the one. I didn't know it was that old. I guess I'll probably have to switch to using the keyboard or curse module.

Comment: @abarnert if the other questions you're referring to are the ones in your first comment, I'm using MacOS and PyCharm(Python 2.7)

Comment: The problem may just be that you’re trying to run it from inside PyCharm. If you run it in a normal Terminal window, does it work?

Comment: As a side note, if you’re a beginner, and testing yourself, is there a reason you’re using 2.7 instead of 3.7?

Comment: @abarnert In a normal terminal window, I get a syntax error trying to download the readchar module(like you said, it's probably because of how it was abandoned). I use Python 2.7 because I think anything later in PyCharm requires you to pay(I'm not a serious coder, so I'm not going to make any investments), and I don't like using the terminal on my Mac.

Comment: PyCharm’s free version works with Python 3.7. You may have to install it (either with an installer from Python.org or Anaconda, or within the IDE), but that’s free too.

Comment: Meanwhile, I don’t know what you mean by “syntax error trying to download”. You shouldn’t need to download anything. Just cd into the directory your script is in and then `python myscript.py`.

Comment: @abarnert In that case, I'll download 3.7. And I think I found out what was wrong(it was a small spelling mistake haha). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable `Emulate terminal in output console` setting in the run configurations section of PyCharm to make it compatible with `termios`.

To get there, either right click in the file editor then click `Modify Run Configuration...`

Or go to the menu bar > `Run` > `Edit Configurations`

Then in the `Execution` section, enable the `Emulate terminal in output console` setting and apply.